# Question about Lp space with p being between 0,1

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I want to know if I can find an example in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that the triangle inequality does not hold with $p\in (0,1)$, hence $L_p$ is not a metric.

I tried several points in $x,y,z$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ but could not reach out, I would appreciate any help or hint regarding this.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\Bbb{R}^2=\ell^p(\{1,2\})$. Let $p=\frac{1}{2}$ and consider $x=(1,0)$, $y=(0,1)$. Then 
$$
\|x\|_{1/2} = ((1)^{1/2} + 0 )^2=1 \text{ and similarly } \| y\|_{1/2}=1
$$
However, $x+y=(1,1)$ and 
$$
\| x+y\|_{1/2}= ((1)^{1/2}+(1)^{1/2})^2 = 4
$$
So it's not true that $\| x+y \|_{1/2} \leq \|x\|_{1/2} + \|y \|_{1/2}$. Therefore the triangle inequality doesn't hold.

Comment: That is actually will work for any $p \in (0,1)$, if we set  $x=(1,0),y=(0,0), z=(0,1)$. Hence, it will work for any $\mathbb{R}^n$ by setiing $x=(1,0,....,0),y=(0,0,...,0),z=(0,1,000,..,0)$

Answer (score 2):

$$ \lVert (1,0) + (0,1) \rVert_p = \lVert (1,1) \rVert_p = (1+1)^{1/p} = 2^{1/p} , $$
while
$$ \lVert (1,0) \rVert_p + \lVert (0,1) \rVert_p = 1^{1/p}+1^{1/p} = 2 , $$
and if $0<p<1$, $2^{1/p} > 2^1 = 2 $ since $t \mapsto 2^{1/p}$ is decreasing.